# How do I calculate insertion loss for a dual input receiver?

Tags: rf, s-parameters, coupler, insertion

Typically my test setup consists of:

Antenna->Antenna Feed Cable->switches->Filter->LNA->Spec An feed Cable->Spec An

I calibrate the cable loss by simply getting the S21 (S1 connected to the Feeding Cable and S2 connected to The spec An feed cable)

My new setup consists of :

Antenna1->Antenna1 Feed Cable-↘️

```
                             ▶️hybrid Coupler->Switch ->… etc
```

Antenna2->Antenna2 Feed Cable-↗️

How do I measure the total insertion loss?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.